# How to sum values in column, grouped by date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following:

```
Name |Dur |DateTime  
Bill |10  |8/12/2018 07:00:00  
Sue  |4   |8/10/2018 09:00:00  
Joe  |23  |8/13/2018 07:15:00  
Bill |13  |8/13/2018 09:15:00  
Sue  |4   |8/10/2018 19:00:00  
Sue  |23  |8/13/2018 07:25:00  
Bill |10  |8/12/2018 15:18:00  
Sue  |4   |8/11/2018 13:00:00  
Joe  |23  |8/14/2018 07:15:00
```

I want to end up with:

```
Name |Tot|Date  
Bill |20 |8/12/2018  
Bill |13 |8/13/2018  
Sue  | 8 |8/10/2018  
Sue  | 4 |8/11/2018  
Joe  |23 |8/13/2018  
Joe  |23 |8/14/2018
```

So basically, sum the Dur each day, for each Name.

I tried:

```
SELECT  
    Name,  
    SUM([Dur]) AS Tot,  
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DateTime], 101)) AS sDateTime  
FROM 
    DailyTransactions   
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DateTime), 0), Name
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You were close... just group by the same logic you used on your column conversion.

```
SELECT  
    Name,  
    SUM([Dur]) AS Tot,  
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DateTime], 101))AS sDateTime  
FROM 
    DailyTransactions   
GROUP BY 
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DateTime], 101))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do your work

```
   SELECT  
        Name,  
        SUM([Dur]) AS Tot,  
        cast(DateTime as Date) AS Date  
    FROM 
        DailyTransactions   
    GROUP BY 
        cast(DateTime as Date), Name
```